# Understanding mongod log entries

Tags: logging, mongodb

Can anyone explain the numbers in the % column, in this mongod log snippet ?
It is building a new index but I'm not sure I understand why the numbers look like that

```
Tue Nov 20 11:38:08 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:49299 #8 (2 connections now open)
Tue Nov 20 11:38:08 [conn8] build index xx.yyyy { source: 1 }
Tue Nov 20 11:38:19 [conn8]         2921300/243339  1200%
Tue Nov 20 11:38:29 [conn8]         4109600/243339  1688%
Tue Nov 20 11:38:39 [conn8]         4400100/243339  1808%
Tue Nov 20 11:38:49 [conn8]         4676600/243339  1921%
Tue Nov 20 11:38:59 [conn8]         4939700/243339  2029%
Tue Nov 20 11:39:09 [conn8]         5217800/243339  2144%
Tue Nov 20 11:39:19 [conn8]         5439300/243339  2235%
Tue Nov 20 11:39:29 [conn8]         5659700/243339  2325%
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from Eliot's comment here:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6333

This can happen if dupes are being deleted and possibly other reasons.  Basically it's an odd, but valid thing to see in certain circumstances and the index build should complete successfully.